# Remove everything after .com python

Tags: python, loops, url

I got this file with this 3 urls insite urls.tmp file:

```
https://site1.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/?SD
https://site2.com.br/wp-content/uploads/tp-datademo/home-4/data/tp-hotel-booking/?SD
https://site3.com.br/wp-content/uploads/revslider/hotel-home/?MD
```

I want to remove everything after "com.br/" of each.

I tryed this code:

```
# open the file
sys.stdout = open("urls.tmp", "w")

# start remove
for i in "urls.tmp":
    url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(i)
    result = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=url_parts)
    print(result) #overwrite the file

# close the file
sys.stdout.close()
```

But the output gave me this stranger thing:

```
:///
:///
:///
:///
:///
:///
:///
:///
```

I'm beginner, what wrong i'm doing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're iterating over `"urls.tmp"` string itself, but want to go through opened file object, line by line.

So try this instead:

```py
with open("urls.tmp", "r") as urls_file:
    for line in urls_file:
        url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(line)
        result = "{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/".format(uri=url_parts)
        print(result)
```

Edit: the author updated the original question mentioning that the source file contents should be rewritten with processed urls, here's the example:

```py
new_urls = []

with open("urls.tmp", "r") as urls_file:
    old_urls = urls_file.readlines()

for line in old_urls:
    url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(line)
    proc_url = "{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/\n".format(uri=url_parts)
    new_urls.append(proc_url)

with open("urls.tmp", "w") as urls_file:
    urls_file.writelines(new_urls)
```

Comment: this code is almost working, but it doesn't overwrite the file (urls.tmp), it erases everything and makes it empty

Comment: It's a really bad idea of reading from and writing to the same file _at the same time_ using two separate streams. So you should pre-process urls first, store them in a list, and then re-open file in write mode to put the new urls back

Comment: Or you could just write your results into a different file in the first place. You can always replace the files by moving them on the OS level.

Comment: @SavvaSurenkov i can save to another file, i tryed here but didn't write with the urls updated. i update my code

Comment: `print` does not save to files. `print` only shows the string on the console. You'd want to use something like [writeFile.writelines](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_writelines.asp)

Comment: @LucasFernandes there're a few problems in the updated code: 1. it prints directly to `sys.stdout` instead of a file, you have to pass a `file=writeFile` option to `print` function; 2. it reopens the destination file in write mode on each iteration, truncating the contents already saved

Answer (score 1):

See [Savva Surenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129011/10504481) answer to solve your issue.

You can use the split method of strings like:

```py
url = r"https://site1.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/?SD"

split_by = "com.br/"

new_url = url.split(split_by)[0] + split_by
# this gives you the part before <split_by> and then we can attach it again
new_url == r"https://site1.com.br"
```

If you want to add some additional checks, you might look into regular expressions.

Things you did not ask for but might help you as a beginner.
I recommend using

```py
with open("urls.tmp", "w") as f:
   # do something with f
```

or

```py
import pathlib

urls = pathlib.Path("urls.tmp").read_text()
# which gives you all lines in single string
```

over plain `open`. If you want to know more about that I recommend looking into context managers.

Also there is `f-strings` since Python 3.6 which are in my opinion easier to read than `"{}".format`.

Comment: This answer completely omits the actual issue with the OP code, i.e. the `for` loop and the file processing. Also in this application IMO it is better to use `urllib` to parse the links, since it is more stable for different ways of writing the same URL.

Comment: in this way i need to know the url's right? i need to assume the url's is genare randomly

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with the find() method of string.

```
urllist=[
'https://site1.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/?SD',
'https://site2.com.br/wp-content/uploads/tp-datademo/home-4/data/tp-hotel-booking/?SD',
'https://site3.com.br/wp-content/uploads/revslider/hotel-home/?MD']

newlist=[]
breaktext='com.br/'
for item in urllist:
    position=item.find(breaktext)
    newlist.append(item[:position+len(breaktext)])

print (newlist)
```